# Evaluating a completely parenthesized arithmetic expression

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, recursion, time-limit-exceeded, math-expression-eval

I tried to solve the following problem in a programming challenge, but the verdict was *time limit exceeded*.

> ***Completely parenthesized expression***
>
> Write a program that reads a completely parenthesized expression, and
>   prints the result of evaluating it. The three possible operators are
>   sum, substraction and multiplication. The operands are natural numbers
>   between 0 and 9 (both included).
>
> **Input**
>
> Input has a completely parenthesized expression. That is, parentheses
>   always appear around subexpressions that are not digits. For instance,
>   the expression `4 + 3` would be written
>
> `( 4 + 3 )`
>
> The expression `8 * (4 + 3)` would be written
>
> `( 8 * ( 4 + 3 ) )`
>
> The expression `(2 − 8) * (4 + 3)` would be written
>
> `((2-8)*(4+3))`
>
> **Output**
>
> Print a line with an integer number: the result of evaluating the
>   given expression.
>
> (Source: https://jutge.org/problems/P45102_en/statement)

Some of the public test cases were (each line is a different test case):

```
9
( 3 + 4 )
( 8 * ( 4 + 3 ) )
( ( 2 - 8 ) * ( 4 + 3 ) )
( ( 3 * 2 ) + 1 )
```

This is my code, which passed every public test cases, but not the private ones. I ask your help in order to find the bottleneck of my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

/**
 * Returns the evaluation of a completely parenthesed expression.
 * 
 * Preconditions:
 *     * 0 <= i <= j < expr.size()-1.
 *     * expr is a completely parenthesed expression.
 * 
 * Postcondition: returns the evaluation of expr[i..j].
 */

int evaluate(const string& expr, int i, int j)
{
    // Skip leading blanks
    while (expr[i] == ' ') {
        ++i;
    }
    while (expr[j] == ' ') {
        --j;
    }

    // Base case
    if (i == j) {
        return expr[i] - '0';
    }
    // Recursive case
    else {
        // Skip first and last parentheses
        ++i;
        --j;
        int open_parentheses = 0;
        int end_i = i;
        // Loop invariant:
        //     * expr[i..end_i) is part of the first subexpression of expr[i..j]
        //     * open_parentheses is the balance of opened and closed parentheses of expr[i..end_i)
        while (open_parentheses > 0 || (expr[end_i] != '+' && expr[end_i] != '-' && expr[end_i] != '*')) {
            if (expr[end_i] == '(') {
                ++open_parentheses;
            }
            else if (expr[end_i] == ')') {
                --open_parentheses;
            }
            ++end_i;
        }
        // Loop ending: expr[end_i] is the 'main' operation of expr[i..j]

        char operation = expr[end_i];

        // By induction hypothesis,
        //     evaluate(expr, i, end_i - 1) 
        // and
        //     evaluate(expr, end_i + 1, j)
        // return the values of the first and the second subexpression of expr[i..j]

        if (operation == '+') {
            return evaluate(expr, i, end_i - 1) + evaluate(expr, end_i + 1, j);
        } else if (operation == '-') {
            return evaluate(expr, i, end_i - 1) - evaluate(expr, end_i + 1, j);
        } else {
            int first_expression = evaluate(expr, i, end_i - 1);
            // Multiplication shortcut
            if (first_expression == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return first_expression * evaluate(expr, end_i + 1, j);   
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string expr;
    getline(cin, expr);
    cout << evaluate(expr, 0, expr.size() - 1) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a *pass* verdict with the following code.

Some comments:

- Moved from `int`s to `string::const_iterator`s. Inefficiency was here.
- Didn't move to `isspace`. I'm sure it is a better option if efficiency is not *that* important, but failed in efficiency terms.
- I've simplified the recursion decision block.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

typedef string::const_iterator it;


/**
 * Returns the evaluation of a completely parenthesed expression.
 * 
 * Preconditions:
 *     * i and j point to characters of expr.
 *     * expr is a completely parenthesed expression.
 * 
 * Postcondition: returns the evaluation of expr[i..j].
 */
int evaluate(const string& expr, it i, it j)
{
    // Skip leading blanks
    while (*i == ' ') {
        ++i;
    }
    while (*j == ' ') {
        --j;
    }

    // Base case
    if (i == j) {
        return *i - '0';
    }

    // Recursive case
    // Skip first and last parentheses
    ++i;
    --j;
    int open_parentheses = 0;
    it end_i = i;
    // Loop invariant:
    //     * expr[i..end_i) is part of the first subexpression of expr[i..j]
    //     * open_parentheses is the balance of opened and closed parentheses of expr[i..end_i)
    while (open_parentheses > 0 || (*end_i != '+' && *end_i != '-' && *end_i != '*')) {
        if (*end_i == '(') {
            ++open_parentheses;
        }
        else if (*end_i == ')') {
            --open_parentheses;
        }
        ++end_i;
    }
    // Loop ending: *end_i is the 'main' operation of expr[i..j]

    char operation = *end_i;

    it begin_j = end_i;
    ++begin_j;
    --end_i;
    int first = evaluate(expr, i, end_i);
    if (operation == '*') {
        if (first == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int second = evaluate(expr, begin_j, j);
            return first * second;   
        }
    } else {
        int second = evaluate(expr, begin_j, j);
        if (operation == '+') {
            return first + second;
        } else {
            return first - second;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    string expr;
    getline(cin, expr);
    it i, j;
    i = expr.begin();
    j = expr.end();
    --j;
    cout << evaluate(expr, i, j) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Use Iterators**
The `int i` and `int j` are unnecessary parameters in `int evaluate(const std::string& expr, int i, int j)`.
The string class is a standard container class. Standard container classes provide the `begin()` and
`end()` functions that provide iterators to the first element and the last element of the container.
This [StackOverflow.com Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices) highlights why iterators are good.

This [StackOverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422835/c-string-iterator) provides a possible example for finding the last character to process.

Using iterators will be faster than using indexing by integer. In C++11 or later the following loop
will advance the iterator until non-white space characters are found in the string.

```
for (auto CharInExperession : exper)
{
    if (!isspace(*CharInExperssion)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

**Use Standard C++ functions to check for white space**
In the example above `isspace()` is used, this checks for all white space, not just space so it checks for
tabs, spaces and new lines. See [isspace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) for information on how to use it.

**Reduce the Complexity of the Code**
There is no reason to have the else clause for `if(i == j) {`, the code in the else clause can be out-dented
because of the return in the if-then portion.